# Ctrl-Space in Eclipse without Pressing Ctrl-Space

Tags: eclipse

I've just started using Eclipse and I noticed that when I start typing a local variable name it doesn't come up with suggestions like Visual Studio does until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.  Is there any way to get it to do this automatically?  I find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> an awkward key press.

Comment: I hope this eventually gets "answered" by a bug fix. I want this too. I don't even remember how I know about CTRL-Space. Does it bring it up in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

These bugs (and a solution if you use Eclipse >3.4) may be of interest to you:

A. Allow more character triggers as @Samuel said (fixed in 3.4 onwards):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159157
[image: add the characters below to content assist in Preferences]

Change the default in *Auto activation triggers for Java* to `._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

B. Allow content assist everywhere automatically (not fixed):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=101420

Comment: So a 4½ year old bug that would make Eclipse work like Visual Studio, isn't fixed yet? Any ideas why they postponed a feature who imo. is more important than anything else they done the last 4 years.

Comment: There maybe another bug open for it that I missed... I think it's a feature eclipse should probably have too.

Comment: So I think the answer is that the feature doesn't exist and it's a bug?

Comment: Interesting, a 4.5 year old bug, and this was 4 years ago...? I had to apply this for xml, and java still isn't fixed.

Comment: I set mine to ".abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_" -- we'll see how it works out. ;-)

Comment: Any idea what a CDT user can do? These options are not available in CDT.

Comment: STILL need to add this for Eclipse Neon.

Use the following to have Annotations autocomplete as well:

._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_@

Comment: Almost end of 2019 and it's still not fixed. Almost 10 years now. Someone should notify Eclipse that the bug status is not "VERIFIED FIXED".

Answer (score 25):

What works:

Change the Auto activation triggers to `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_`

You're unlikely to type anything else to get assist started.

Comment: P.S. A small part of me just died doing that.

Comment: For that you have Ctrl+Space! Also, space doesn't trigger InteliiSense.

Comment: But why not add space in the list to trigger "auto-activation"?

Comment: You don't need to delimit the list with commas and you might want to add ABCDEF etc. In fact, here is the entire string `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_`.

Comment: how can I disable space from selecting one of the choises

Comment: 2022 and its still no fixed lol

Answer (score 12):

1. Window -> Preferences
2. Java -> Editor -> Content Assist
3. Change auto-activation to suit your preferences

You will probably want to set the delay to 0.

Comment: These are the settings I have.  I don't think it will trigger auto assist until you type ".".

Comment: If you can put multiple triggers you might want to try putting all the letters in that box so it would work sort of like VS

Comment: How would you add every single possible letter in the alphabet to it then? ;-)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen What problem do you see? That's what Markus Keller suggests in his [comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159157#c12) to eclipse bug 159157 mentioned by Scobal.

Comment: What problem? That it very simply, doesn't trigger on every single keyboard input, including space. That Eclipse can't do proper autocompletion/intellisense like Visual Studio just shows the pure ignorance of the developers.

Comment: Simply set `Auto activation triggers for Java` to `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_`. It now behaves like IntelliSense.

Comment: It works, @CallumRogers. But I'm not sure why it works for pressing a space when you don't have that in the trigger list.

Comment: Actually you should add " ", space, and "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" too.

Answer (score 5):

Also to make Auto Complete work in XML files do the following changes in 
Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor -> Content Assist

Under Auto Activation section, provide the following values

1. Make Auto activation delay (ms):  0
2. Prompt when these characters are inserted: <=:._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Following screenshot explains the same

[image]