# Make Eclipse autocomplete arguments in method implementation

Tags: c++, eclipse

Can I somehow make Eclipse autocomplete arguments in a method I am implementing?

Let's say I have

```
class A {
  void foo(const string& some_long_descriptive_name);
};
```

in the header. Now in the body I start type void `A::foo(` and I here I would like to just hit some button and get my argument(s) automatically filled in. Is that possible?

Comment: Seem to be already asked here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912169/eclipse-enable-autocomplete-content-assist Did you try the solution proposed?

Comment: Nope, I know how to autocomplete symbols in general. I can't autocomplete method arguments when implementing it.

Comment: Ok, sorry, now I undestand your question: you want to have an autocompletion when you are defining the function after the declaration... Seems pretty specific, not something you'll so often to require an autocompletion. Yet, it could be useful.

Comment: I have to type some stuff twice, feels like a thing a computer could do the second time. It has all the information at hand.

Comment: Well, I usually do copy and paste, and I usually do some mistakes because of that :) (but usually just compile time errors, not runtime ones)

Comment: Eclipse does even pop up a small window showing the parameter types and names from the declaration when you request autocomplete inside the parentheses or pause immediately after typing `(`.  So it has the information.  There just doesn't seem to be a nice way to have it dump that information into the source.