# Content assist on eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've `eclipse mars` installed in two different machines.

One provides autocomplete, suggestions, and it imports util packages without me even noticing.

The other one does not do any of this, unless I press **ctrl+space** which defeats the purpose.

I've compared the **content assist** and **auto complete options** on both machines and they are the same.

On this example I don't have to do anything to be given the instance of option, and as soon as I type the letter p it brings up the Printable interface option. The other one not do so much.

What other settings should I check?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

[Eclipse: Enable autocomplete / content assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912169/eclipse-enable-autocomplete-content-assist)

Try auto-activation > auto-activation for triggers.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default eclipse java editor will only show suggestions in content assist only after entering dot(.). This can be customized.

If you want eclipse to show up content assistant for every character you press then you need to enter following text **.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ** to **Auto Activation triggers of java** setting.

[image]