# Enable autocomplete in Eclipse 2020-03 for C/C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, autocomplete

I know about the `Ctrl+Space` shortcut to open the autocomplete menu but I am trying to enable it by default like in the text editor Sublime, for example. So I don't have to press the combination each time.

Comment: This should be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912169/eclipse-enable-autocomplete-content-assist

Comment: I am aware of this question but it was in 2011 and thought maybe it's resolved clearly in 2020

Comment: No changes. The mechanism itself using any specified character to trigger the autocompletion is considered extremely flexible to don't require any change.

Comment: The link above refers to content assist settings for Java. Seems to be quite different for C++. I cannot see a way to customize the trigger characters for C++ editor. Only checkboxes to enable/disable the defaults.