# Eclipse not opening proper autofill

Tags: java, eclipse

Yesterday I updated to Eclipse 2020-06, and everything seemed to be working fine. This morning I opened a different workspace, and the autofill doesn't show classed in my project.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYqoM.jpg - I had to take this picture on my phone since autofill went away when I tried opening snipping tool. I've tried restarting eclipse, and I'm not sure what causes this.

Comment: Does this help? [Eclipse: Enable autocomplete / content assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912169/eclipse-enable-autocomplete-content-assist)

Answer (score 1):

I went to Window > Preferences > Content Assist > Advanced and turned everything on, and it seems to be working now.