# Enable javascript content assist in Eclipse JEE

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, content-assist, eclipse-jee

I create a dynamic web project use JSP file. When I click `CTRL + SPACE`, the notification is:

> No JavaScript Proposals

JSP file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap450/js/bootstrap.js">
    /* HERE, When I click `CTRL + SPACE`, the notification is `No JavaScript Proposals`. */
    </script>
    
  </head>
.....
.....
```

I've clicked *`Enable auto activation`* in the JavaScript section in preferences:

[image: preferences]

Environment : MAC OS and Eclipse JEE Photon.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912169/eclipse-enable-autocomplete-content-assist) the reference related this, but not solve my issue.

Is it possible to make Eclipse JEE to show javascript content assist in `<script>` tag?

**Project Structure**:

```
|-myproject
  |-Deployment Descriptor: myproject
  |-JAX-WS Web Services 
  |-Java Resources
  |-JavaScript Resources
  |-build
  |-WebContent
    |-bootstrap450
      |-css
      |-js
        |-bootstrap.min.js
    |-META-INF
    |-WEB-INF
      |-lib
      |-web.xml
    |-index.jsp
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the project's JavaScript setup look like? Are the ECMA libraries on its include path? The WebContent folder? Is `Window` set as the global supertype?

Comment: Hi @nitind thanks for reply, question updated. I don't know about ECMA libraries, all file in `WebContent -> WEB-INF` how to resolve?

Comment: It should be correctly set up by default, then. It might be because JSDT doesn't really work well with minimized JavaScript files. Also, nothing in WEB-INF can be directly served to clients, you'll want to move your JSP, CSS, and JavaScript files out of there.

Comment: @nitind Apologies, actually the JSP, CSS, and JavaScript files outside the `WEB-INF` folder, JSDT installed, and `.../js/bootstrap.min.js` changed to `.../js/bootstrap.js` . I've updated the question in structure project, how do I proceed?