# Eclipse no intellisense for Android Development for Layouts

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting started with Android Development and having trouble to get the suggestion box/intellisense to work in XML layouts.

I read number of articles suggesting to update the content assist settings for "Other Java Proposals" but there is no option for that.

[image]

So, currently I do not have any suggestions popping up in my layout pages.

Comment: Are you sure you opening your XML file with 'Android Common XML Editor' and not just 'XML Editor' ?

Comment: You are right! That was the problem. Even if I open with Android Common Editor I still have to press "Control + Space" to see the options in layout files. Is there any way I should just see options as I start typing.

Comment: I am including my comment as the answer. could you accept it and mark it as an answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening your XML file with `Android Common XML Editor` rather than opening it as just an `XML File`.

As for Ctrl + space, follow this question:
[Ctrl-Space in Eclipse without Pressing Ctrl-Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959946/ctrl-space-in-eclipse-without-pressing-ctrl-space)