# Eclipse Java auto-complete for current class methods

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-juno

Using a very recent version of Eclipse Juno, auto-complete on Java method calls using `Ctrl+Space` fails to work unless the `this` keyword is used.

I believe this is non-default behaviour; I'm sure use of `this` wasn't required the last time I used the IDE.

Is anyone aware of a fix?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959946/ctrl-space-in-eclipse-without-pressing-ctrl-space).

Changing the activation trigger as described in several answers in the linked thread solves the problem.