# Auto complete xth Item in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When you have opened the Auto-complete menu in Eclipse (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), is there any functionality to, for example, press 4 and then pick 4th item in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.It will come based on the  letter as you typed.

Comment: alphabetical and camel case is all i know

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959946/ctrl-space-in-eclipse-without-pressing-ctrl-space.It might be useful for u