# Turn on Eclipse autosuggest but not autocomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, autosuggest, content-assist

I have turned on Eclipse autocomplete (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959946/ctrl-space-in-eclipse-without-pressing-ctrl-space)).
But im facing a problem. eg. - When I type `fg` to use as my method name, Eclipse shown auto-suggestions. Thats ok. But when I press `(` for the method Eclipse autocompletes it as `FFmpegFrameGrabber(`, which I dont want.

Is there any way so that Eclipse shows autosuggestions but autocompletes when I press "arrow down" and then,"enter" .(One way would be to increase `Auto activation delay`,but i want it to be 0 ms )

Any other way ?