# How to make autosuggestion work for XML in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

In `eclipse`, `content-assist` can be made to work pretty well for `.java` files as described in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959946/ctrl-space-in-eclipse-without-pressing-ctrl-space) answers. I wanna know can we achieve similar autosuggestion for XML files as well? Moreover, I am working on `Spring` framework. I want `eclipse` to display `Spring` specific keywords as well. For example,suggest `constructor-arg` when I type `constru` in my `Spring.xml`.

Comment: The basic Eclipse XML editor should already do that, provided that you are referring the correct XSD in the XML's header. What are you currently using? (Using Neon here, with no special XML editor plugins installed)

Comment: Actually, is this question about generally having autocomplete-suggestions for XML, or about how to get those even without using Ctrl-Space, as in the linked question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Spring Tool Suite (STS) or install that plugin into Eclipse. That will do what you want.